# Laravel 5.1: Unable to get form data in middleware

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5.1, middleware

I have a form submission that posts to `indexController@postSwitch`. I get the submitted data in the `postSwitch` action, but when I do the same thing in my middleware, it returns null. This is a global middleware, and I'm just trying to see if I have access to the submitted data. This [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) shows that I should be able to get the form data.

Like this..

```
// Form: just a simple form that posts `id` to /switch     

// Complete routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@dashboard');
    Route::post('/switch', 'IndexController@postSwitch');
    Route::get('/settings', 'IndexController@settings');
});

Route::get('auth/login',  'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
Route::get('auth/register',  'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');


// Middleware
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');   
    dd($id);  // null
    return $next($request);
}

// IndexController@switch
public function postSwitchBrand(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');  // Has the submitted data
}
```

This middleware is registered globally. i.e. appended to the `$middleware` property in `\App\Http\Kernel`. What am I missing?

Comment: Is that the only route you have? I suspect that, since you have a global route, It will be executed for every HTTP call. So, are you sure you are seeing a correct log?

Comment: Added all of the routes. I don't quite follow. I want this middleware to be used for every request.

Comment: I mean to say that, your form `POST` on `switch`. However, since you have a global middleware, your middleware code will be executed for all of the routes. That includes the `GET` routes as well, which basically won't post any data to the server, hence making the id `null`.

Comment: I have a similar setup, tested it, I receive all the data I post in my middleware. I think my above comment points at the exact problem.

Comment: Even if the middleware is used for all routes/requests (I want it to be), shouldn't a particular `post` to `switch` make the submitted data available from the request, `$request`? I tried `['middleware' => ['auth', 'switch']` in the routes instead of global, but still null.

Comment: Yeah, that should work and it is actually working in my setup. That's strange. But, I'm sending my data as a JSON. Let me try form-data and get back here

Comment: Yes, form-data isn't accessible. I support your question

Comment: Weird. I'm going to have to re-read the documentation. I'll post an update if I find anything later!

Comment: I read it, they haven't mentioned anything specific to content type.

Comment: Ah ha. Looks like `$request` needs to be processed (`$response = $next($request)`) before the form data is incorporated into it. Taking a look at `$_POST` anywhere in the middleware's `handle()` method shows the submitted data is there! Wanna write up an answer for it, so I can give you credit?

Comment: But that totally depends on the use case isn't it? What If I want my middleware to be processed `before` it hits my controller? The above will make the middleware code to be processed `after` it hits the controller

Comment: Hm, you're right. I'm storing a session value in this middleware to be used in fetching data for the view. I'm going to play around a little more how it affects my application. Liking Laravel so far, though.

Answer (score 3):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I see that there is a small glitch here, which is not defined in the documentation. I've raised an Issue on [laravel Git repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework) stating the problem there.

Here's the link to the issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11278

Link on the laravel Forum :: http://laravel.io/forum/12-11-2015-form-data-not-accessible-in-middleware-via-request

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following:

```
    $request->id;
```

To access request parameters.

Comment: This will not give the form data.

Answer (score -1):

It is tricky but looks as though something like the following works:

$request->getContent()

or if getting a json payload for the request:

$request->json()